# Is it possible to disable or deactivate (not remove or uninstall) a Python version in Ubuntu18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, python, python3

I want to disable or deactivate (not remove) Python 2.7 from Ubuntu 18.04. Is it possible to do it. If so, then how?

Comment: I don't get why are you trying to do that. Could you add more information about what you want to reach? You can easily re-install any package, so removing them is not a big deal. You can also keep an offline installation package at hand. Or maybe you want  to create virtual Python environments, if you need to isolate a program from an installation.

Comment: I am working on a project. It's a modified version of bottle.py. Before it was running on python 2. I want to update it to three. So i installed a virtual environment of python 3.7. but on restarting the apache service its still printing ( [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23927] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/2.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
) which means its still running in python2.

Comment: so i want to debug it by disabling the python2 from my version since i see no virtualenv other than what i created. than i think its accesing default version installed on my os

Comment: could it be that i need to install mod_wsgi for python3.7 too

Comment: The Ubuntu package would be `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`.  If you uninstall `libapache2-mod-wsgi`, then Apache should no longer use Python 2.7

Comment: Thanks mate That did work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Ubuntu specifically (a Fedora user myself), but Python is a nice tool to build (non performance critical, for example GUI) system administration tools. And lots of other things. I *might* be able to uninstall Python, but that would leave me without many very useful tools. Fedora is in the process of purging Python 2 from the distribution, the process isn't yet finished as far as I know (and I have some third party programs installed in my accout that still work only with Python 2).